# The resource object with key was not found In Asp.net with VB web application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, globalization

I have developed asp.net web application using VB. Now I want my web application in multi languages. So I have try to add Global resources for multi language.

When I try to use global resource key in my user control then it gives me below error.

```
“Exception message: The resource object with key 'FirstText' was not found.”

<asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:DisplayLang, FirstText%>"> </asp:Label>
```

I have also web application in C# that is perfectly work but In Visual Basic Project not get any resources key and also do not make .dll file in bin folder.